# Python sort_values (inplace=True) but not really?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to write a loop in python as I have to compare rows to each other in a table.  I have to sort the data, which I do by 'sort_values', the dataframe seems to sort, yet when I step through it with a 'for loop' it is still unsorted?  So I'm clearly not understanding how pandas memory allocation works.  I have tried sorting to another dataframe and I get the same problem

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
        'date1': ['2000-04-18', '2000-04-16', '2000-04-15', '2000-04-25', '2000-04-16', '2000-04-17'],
        'stat1': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9, 3.2]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data) 
 
frame
```

```
output original unsorted:
 state  date1   stat1
0   Ohio    2000-04-18  1.5
1   Ohio    2000-04-16  1.7
2   Ohio    2000-04-15  3.6
3   Nevada  2000-04-25  2.4
4   Nevada  2000-04-16  2.9
5   Nevada  2000-04-17  3.2
```

```
frame.sort_values(by=['state','date1'], inplace=True)

frame
```

```
sorted output:
    state   date1   stat1
4   Nevada  2000-04-16  2.9
5   Nevada  2000-04-17  3.2
3   Nevada  2000-04-25  2.4
2   Ohio    2000-04-15  3.6
1   Ohio    2000-04-16  1.7
0   Ohio    2000-04-18  1.5
```

```
for i1 in range(0, len(frame)):
    state1=frame['state'][i1]
    print(frame['state'][i1],' ', frame['date1'][i1])
```

```
output unsorted:
Ohio   2000-04-18
Ohio   2000-04-16
Ohio   2000-04-15
Nevada   2000-04-25
Nevada   2000-04-16
Nevada   2000-04-17
```

Comment: It looks like when using a for loop, pandas iterates over index. You can potentially fix it by either running `reset_index(inplace=True)` after sorting or by not using a `for` loop.

Comment: @pavel *pandas* doesn't do anything. The OP is using `range` to iterate over a range of integers. Of course, the dataframe maintained the index it had at the beginning, as one should expect. So if course, you get the original order

Comment: You shouldnt be using a dataframe like this to begin with. If you *must* then use `for row in df.itertuples():`

Comment: Yeah, I missed that OP did `in range(len(frame))` , I thought it was just `in frame:` @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @pavel that would iterate over the column labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset indices to see the correct order in the loop:

```
frame.sort_values(by=['state','date1'], inplace=True).reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Otherwise, when iterating over the data frame, it moves forward based on the row indices. Hence, you can see the same order as you had in the original data frame. You can also verify the fact by looking at the indices in your examples.

Comment: You don't *have* to. If the OP wants to iterate over a dataframe then that's what they should do, but they aren't. They are iterating over a `range` object

Comment: @OmG , that solved it.  ```frame.sort_values(by=['state','date1'], inplace=True)
frame.reset_index(inplace = True)```  Though it does now show and 'index' and a new row, it is not sorting on the index, but the results are good.  I don't know how to accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage  - I would do df.tertuples():  though how to do you an inner loop then, like to tell it now compare row10 to row11, then compare row10 to row12, then.....?  LIke ```for i1 in range(0, len(frame)):
    state1=frame['state'][i1]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage  - I would do df.tertuples():  though how to do you an inner loop then, like to tell it now compare row1 to row2, then compare row1 to row3, then.....?  LIke ```for i1 in range(0, len(frame)):
    state1=frame['state'][i1]   for i2 in range(i1+1,len(frame)) if (frame['stat2'][i1]>frame[stat1][i2]*2):  frame['level'][i1]='green'